# in c how preprocessor(#) get evaluated ? not understanding the output of this program

Tags: c, logic

what would be the output of this program ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define s(x)x*x
int main()
{ printf("%d",s(5+1));

      return 0;
}
```

the output of this code is 11 how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `5 + 1 * 5 + 1` is `11`. The multiplication comes first, `1 * 5`, so you're left with `5 + 5 + 1` => `11`.

To get `36`, change your macro to:

```
#define s(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Which will then become `((5 + 1) * (5 + 1))` => `(6 * 6)` => `(36)`

Comment: need parens around each x

Comment: @stark Indeed, fixed :)